# How can I get browserify's "bundle" function to emit an end event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify, browser-sync

Say I have some relatively generic browserify scaffolding intended to be used with gulp:

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var browserify  = require('browserify');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var exorcist = require('exorcist');

var bundler = browserify('app.jsx', {
  debug: false,
  extensions: ['.jsx'],
  cache: {},
  packageCache: {}
});

function bundle() {
  return bundler.bundle()
    .on('error', function(err) {
        gutil.log(err.message);
        browserSync.notify('Browserify error!');
        this.emit('end');
    })
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(transform(function () {
      return exorcist('public/js/app.js.map');
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream({ once: true }))
}
```

My issue is that gulp 4 needs explicit notification of completion of tasks, which `bundle()` as above does not provide:

```
gulp.task('js', function(callback) {
  return bundle();
})
```

Gulp 4 output:

> `[timestamp] The following tasks did not complete: js`
>
> `[timestamp] Did you forget to signal async completion?`

However, `bundle()` doesn't emit an 'end' event on its own, so the below makes the same error:

```
gulp.task('js', function(callback) {
  bundle().on('end', callback);
});
```

How do I get this function to emit an 'end' event after the last `.pipe()` call, or otherwise get gulp 4 to recognize the task is finished [according to the API docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/API.md)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the underlying issue is, but removing the exorcist line in the pipe fixes my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is that of passing `callback`, and not calling it. If `callback` is undefined, all you need to do is return a stream.

The following should do the trick:

```
gulp.task('js', function () { return bundle(); });
```

As should this:

```
gulp.task('js', function (cb) { bundle().on('end', cb); });
```

You either *return* or *invoke the callback*, don't mix the two.

I could be wrong here, but I *think* the general recommendation is to return.